# Get Facebook creative id through graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I’m looking for a solution to get the ad post id, in the page post, when I create an ad creative from the graph api.

I simply cannot get it through the graph api, because it’s linked to the business manager.

Any ideas, how I can get the id from the graph api - or how I can create a page post with the specifications from the ad creative.

I’ve tried almost everything, and I’m just stuck.

I can create the page post manually by copying the id and paste it into the api. But I can’t fetch it from their graph api.. or am I just missing something?